# Convert from Scientic notation(1.805291706224803e+17) to normal (180529170622480277)

Tags: python-3.x

I am comparing data using panda lib, between Teradata table and GCP table.
I have `sql :where prod_dim_id=180529170622480277` , GCP reading and displaying exactly same.
But after bringing data to data frame from Teradata it is displaying as  `1.805291706224803e+17`.

How to display as it is.

```py
source_df_orderedd_sql = pd.read_sql(query3,session)
print(source_df_orderedd_sql.dtypes)
PROD_DIM_ID    float64
dtype: object
```

I want to display no as it is from DB without any modification.

Comment: large floating point numbers are displayed in exponential notation by default. To change that, you'll have to format the number - e.g. if `v` is your value, you could use `print(f"{v:.0f}")` here.

Comment: note: `pandas.read_sql` returns a `float` by default (if you don't set `coerce_float=False`); you could consider making it an `integer` in the first place since your IDs seem to be of that type.